# select a datagrid cell that contains a given value in wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I bound a DataTable to a datagrid in wpf. The first column has unique values. Now I would like to autoselect a cell in the second column whose first column cell has the given value. How should I achieve that? For example，here is my datagrid:

Name | Age 
 cat     |  2 
 dog    | 3

When user input 'dog', I will need the '3' to be selected.

I tried the method show here:
 
[How to select a row or a cell in WPF DataGrid programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836191/how-to-select-a-row-or-a-cell-in-wpf-datagrid-programmatically)
However, I cannot figure out the displaying row number. Even though I know the row number of the dataTable, the display number can be different since I allow users to sort the table.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your grid's SelectionUnit property to "Cell", and assuming you feed the DataGrid with the table's DefaultView:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Search for the source-row.
  var Element = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == "horse");

  if (Element == null) return;

  // Found the row number in the DataGrid
  var RowOnGrid = MyGrid.Items.OfType<DataRowView>()
    .Select((a, Index) => new { data=a.Row, index = Index })
    .Where(x=> x.data == Element)
    .Select(x => x.index)
    .FirstOrDefault();

  // Assuming the desired column is the second one.
  MyGrid.SelectedCells.Clear();
  MyGrid.SelectedCells.Add(new DataGridCellInfo(MyGrid.Items[RowOnGrid], MyGrid.Columns[1]));
}
```

It should work even if you re-sort the rows.

Comment: Wow, what a quick, neat and working answer!! I learned a lot from it. Thanks a million.

Comment: Good to know it worked. By the way, welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you to change your username to something more attractive :o)