# Getting value on datagrid by columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How do you know the value of a particular row in the column titled `id`:

```
 row_index | id
-----------+-----
    0      | 54

    1      | 34

    2      | 12
```

`select id where row_index = 1` for example, I should get a value of 34.

This is `datagrid`.

Comment: I don't get the question

Comment: What errors are you running into?

Comment: Perhaps related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339294/select-a-datagrid-cell-that-contains-a-given-value-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure you looking for this,
Anyway you can access the particular cell value by giving the column name and the row index

```
var value = datagrid["id",rowindex].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: @JohniekComp: For grid-view you can use  [string columnName,int roeIndex]:DataGridViewCell

Comment: @JohniekComp: What is the error you getting with the above code?

Comment: Can not apply indexing by [] to an expression of type System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid