# Search value row in column (datagrid)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting value on datagrid by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306555/getting-value-on-datagrid-by-columns)

How to get the value in column `id` where `index = 3` for example

This is WPF, datagrid

Comment: Please post you source code, and if you are running into errors you stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that yr grid is bound to items/object so if you wanted to change values in that column or row you can simply use this in your grid click event, or what ever event you are using

```
    MyObject rowObject = gridObjects.GetFocusedRow as MyObject;
    if (rowObject != null)
    {

    }
```

Comment: you do not understand the question

Comment: Then use gridview.FocusedRowHandle

Comment: i need select value in column name=id where index row = 3

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to understand your question, if you could add some more information I'm sure you will get a good answer.

What have you tried? And can you add some more code (and context) to the question?

Have you looked at MSDN? Here is one way to get cell value:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5c4a30a.aspx

```
private void GetCellValue(DataGrid myGrid){
   DataGridCell myCell = new DataGridCell();
   // Use and arbitrary cell.
   myCell.RowNumber = 1;
   myCell.ColumnNumber = 1;
   Console.WriteLine(myGrid[myCell]);
}
```

Cheers
--Jocke

Comment: myGrid[myCell] is wrong with wpf foundation!