# Select the wpf datagrid cell at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My scenario:
Data loads in to my data grid page by page
On key down of the last row on w pf data grid, i will load another row in the end. this way after binding with the new rows after key down focus on the last selected cell is lost. i want to retain the selection on the last+1 (row and column) cell. How can i set this.

Answer (score 1):

There is event `SourceUpdated`, so you could do something like that:

```
private void DataGrid_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
   (sender as DataGrid).SelectedIndex = (sender as DataGrid).Items.Count - 1;
}
```

It could help also:
[How to select a row or a cell in WPF DataGrid programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836191/how-to-select-a-row-or-a-cell-in-wpf-datagrid-programmatically)